# Unable to Bulk upload wikipedia json.gz to elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm following the example online to import a json.gz wikipedia dump into elasticsearch: https://www.elastic.co/blog/loading-wikipedia.

After executing the following

```
curl -s 'https://'$site'/w/api.php?action=cirrus-mapping-dump&format=json&formatversion=2' |
 jq .content |
 sed 's/"index_analyzer"/"analyzer"/' |
 sed 's/"position_offset_gap"/"position_increment_gap"/' |
curl -XPUT $es/$index/_mapping/page?pretty -d @-
```

I get an error:

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "mapper_parsing_exception",
        "reason" : "Unknown Similarity type [arrays] for field [category]"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "mapper_parsing_exception",
    "reason" : "Unknown Similarity type [arrays] for field [category]"
  },
  "status" : 400
}
```

Anybody got any ideas? I'm not able to ingest the wikipedia content using the method described. Wish the company would at least update their tutorial page.